# count(*) cannot be selected in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
  rec_count integer default 0;
  str varchar(100);
BEGIN
    str := 'select count(*) into ' || rec_count ||' from emp_table';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (str);
    dbms_output.put_line(rec_count);
END;
```

I cannot get count in rec_count valibale. I received ORA-00905 message.

I have to add these lines in my script so sql statment should be like this. 
I would pass trip name to this script and it would return count of that table.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must use like below

```
DECLARE
  rec_count integer default 0;
  str varchar(100);
BEGIN
    str := 'select count(*) from emp_table';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str into rec_count;
    dbms_output.put_line(rec_count);
END;
```

the `into` clause must be use after `execute immediate`. refer here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm for more information

Comment: Thanks @Exhausted for your help. I have another question regarding this, how can i see output of the procedure in command line via sqlplus.

Comment: You must use `set serveroutput on`. Did you see my answer?

Comment: @abidkhan303 yes as Lalith said

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str into rec_count;`. the `INTO` clause must be used while you do `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    rec_count integer default 0;
  3    str varchar(100);
  4  BEGIN
  5      str := 'select count(*) from emp';
  6      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str into rec_count;
  7      dbms_output.put_line(rec_count);
  8  END;
  9  /
14

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```