# How to see stored procedure output on command line via sqlplus

Tags: oracle, command-line, sqlplus, toad

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC
IS
  str varchar(100);
  rec_count INTEGER;

BEGIN
    str := 'select count(*) from emp_record';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str into rec_count;
    dbms_output.put_line(rec_count);
END;
```

I can see output of this procedure in Toad(for oracle), but when i execute this in command line via sqlplus i see following output

```
SQL> exec test_proc;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

so question is how can i see count output on command line.

Comment: Already answered in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/a/27939284/3989608

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the output in SQL/PLUS before running your stored procedure:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```